# How to Run two different commands using process builder

Tags: java, command-prompt, processbuilder

Sorry if I am Re-opening the same Question again. I want to Run Two Commands

1. D:\cygwin\bin\Test
2. sh app.sh AK-RD 02.20 D:\cygwin\bin\Test_files

Above are the two commands i want to run in the same command prompt Means i have to go inside **D:\cygwin\bin\Test** Folder and on the same prompt want to run next command

**sh app.sh AK-RD 02.20 D:\cygwin\bin\Test_files**

The command will look like,

Command:- **D:\cygwin\bin\Test>sh app.sh AK-RD 02.20 D:\cygwin\bin\Test_files**

How to do this using process Builder in java. Or is there any other way to do this.

```
String cmd;   
   cmd = "sh app.sh AK-RD 02.20 D:\\cygwin\\bin\\Test_files";
    ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( cmd );
    probuilder.directory(new File("D:\\cygwin\\bin\\Test"));
    Process process = probuilder.start();
```

This is not Helping me, Even if i change `probuilder.directory` in the code. I am getting

```
Cannot run program "'sh app.sh AK-RD 02.20 D:\\cygwin\\bin\\Test_files  CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means the system can't find the file `sh app.sh AK-RD 02.20 D:\\cygwin\\bin\\Test_files.exe` in the path.

This means that `ProcessBuilder` interprets the whole string (including backslashes and spaces and everything) as command name. This is not what you want.

Split the command into individual words:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "sh", "app.sh", "AK-RD", "02.20", "D:\\cygwin\\bin\\Test_files" );
```

and use `pb.directory()` to `CD` into the correct directory.

Alternatively, put everything into a BAT/CMD script and run that with `ProcessBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pd.directory(new File("D:\\cygwin\\bin\\Test"));
```

to set the working directory.

Edit:

You can also try and split your command into arguments

```
String cmd[] = new String[5];
cmd[0] = "sh";
cmd[1] = "app.sh";
cmd[2] = "AK-RD";
cmd[3] = "02.20";
cmd[4] = "D:\\cygwin\\bin\\Test_files";
```

Comment: Can u tell how exactly it should be because i am getting Error CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: I've seen some strange behavior when not splitting commands into arguments. Does the splitting work for you? No love still?